# AtmosphereResource is coming out to be null.

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, atmosphere

Hi I followed the link: [How to design push notifications using Atmosphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929175/how-to-design-push-notifications-using-atmosphere)

To design push notifications, but am getting a null AtmosphereResource after line:`AtmosphereResource resource = (AtmosphereResource)request.getAttribute(ApplicationConfig.ATMOSPHERE_RESOURCE);`

I have used the code:
 `AtmosphereFramework f = new AtmosphereFramework();
        f.init();`
in main function as mine is spring boot application.

For installing Atmosphere using the wiki: https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Installing-Atmosphere

The client side code is same as the answer specifies

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the mistake..
Had to add the code: `f.doCometSupport(AtmosphereRequest, AtmosphereResponse);`
when my request comes in.